# How do I add a reverse field value into the django serializer data set

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a parent id in an object that contains child data.  I want to add another field value from the parent id into the serializer for the child table to return back to the view

I made a nested serializer, but the literature only focuses on updating the parent and child object.  I only want to update the child object, but I want a field from the parent object added to the data of the serializer.

The reverse relationship is especially confusing because 1. it didn't work for me, and 2. the example here uses it on a parent item which was already used as an example of a forward relationship.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

```
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['choice_text', 'votes', 'question']

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choice = ChoiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['id', 'question_text', 'choice']

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)# Create your models here.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

s = ChoiceSerializer(data={'choice_text':'tests','votes': 50, 'question':1})
s.is_valid()
s.save()
```

I got this from s.data:
ReturnDict([('choice_text', 'tests'), ('votes', 50), ('question', 1)])

I would prefer this:
ReturnDict([('choice_text', 'tests'), ('votes', 50), ('question_test', 'hello')])

Comment: You accidentally left off the rest of the `Meta` class for your `QuestionSerializer`, which is needed to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little clumsy with the mouse in jupyter notebooks

Answer (score 0):

Mostly for this requirement to change/add additional information from model instance serialize data one possible way to do that is to use [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

In addition we may want to use same serializer for updating data and also for getting serialize data for response. what i want to mean during saving information through serializer we need `question` field but during retrive data we need `question_test`.

```py
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    question_test = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['choice_text', 'votes', 'question', 'question_test']
        extra_kwargs = {'question': {'write_only': True}}



    def get_question_test(self, obj):
        return obj.question.question_test
```

Comment: You're write_only true led me to this: https://medium.com/@sarit.r/read-only-write-only-in-django-rest-serializer-670935a710f4, but that didn't work for me.  Yours didn't either.  It said Field name `question_test` is not valid for model `question`

Comment: But IT DOES WORK if you make it get_question_test.  Do I check it as the solution now, or do I ask you to edit your answer first?  What's the etiquette here?  It was just yesterday that I learned you use three back ticks, NOT APOSTROPHES to do the whole code block thingy, so I don't mean to disrespect.  I'm very excited now.

Comment: sorry my typo, I have edited my response. I think first we should correct the working code and then accept it. As same problem may lead others here.