# How do I add a reverse field value into the django serializer data set Part 2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I previously asked a similar question:
[How do I add a reverse field value into the django serializer data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58159882/how-do-i-add-a-reverse-field-value-into-the-django-serializer-data-set)

But oddly, what worked for the first model doesn't work for the second.  Here are my models:

```
class ae(models.Model):
    opp_own = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class statement_line(models.Model):
    ae = models.ForeignKey(ae, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    pay_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    approve_date = models.DateField()
    opp_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    document_number = models.CharField(null=True,max_length = 50,)
    ct_id = models.CharField(max_length = 50,validators=[
        RegexValidator(regex='^CT',
                       message='this didn\'t come from salesforce'
                       )])
    amt = models.FloatField()
    cur = models.CharField(default='USD',max_length = 3)

class draws(models.Model):
    ae = models.ForeignKey(ae, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    draw_type = models.CharField(choices=[('incentive pay','incentive pay'),('recoverable draw','recoverable draw')], max_length = 50)
    amt = models.FloatField()
    usd_amt = models.FloatField()
    cur = models.CharField(choices=[('USD','USD'),('EUR','EUR'),('AUD','AUD'),('IND','IND'),('GBP','GBP')],default='USD', max_length = 3)
    owe_date = models.DateField()
    sl = models.ForeignKey(statement_line, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null = True)
```

This works fine:

```
class drawsSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    opp_own = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = draws
        fields = ['id','ae_id', 'ae','owe_date','draw_type','usd_amt','amt', 'opp_own']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'ae': {'write_only': True}        
        }

    def get_opp_own(self, obj):
        return obj.ae.opp_own
goods = draws.objects.filter(sl_id__isnull=True).order_by('-owe_date')
serializer = drawsSerializer2(goods,many=True)
serializer.data
```

But inexplicably, this doesn't:

```
class statement_lineSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    opp_own = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = statement_line
        fields = ['id','ae_id','ae','pay_date','opp_name','type','document_number','ct_id','amt','cur','opp_own']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'ae': {'write_only': True}        
        }

    def get_opp_own(self, obj):
        return obj.ae.opp_own

goods2 = statement_line.objects.filter(pay_date__isnull=True).order_by('-approve_date')
sl = ae_statement_lineSerializer2(goods2,many=True)
sl.data
```

Instead I get this:
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `opp_own` on serializer `ae_statement_lineSerializer2`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `statement_line` instance.
Original exception text was: 'statement_line' object has no attribute 'opp_own'.

I don't know what the background magic is actually doing and probably have to swim through the code to figure it out.  It must be something stupidly obvious.  Is it something stupidly obvious?  And now its memorialized on the internet for all to see.  serializerMethodFields, nested serializers; Everytime I have to look up a value from a foreign table in django I have a panic attack.

Comment: Is there a difference between `statement_lineSerializer2` versus `ae_statement_lineSerializer2`?

Comment: That was the problem.  I can't believe it, I didnt' make a class called ae_statement_lineSerializer2, but somehow one was run.  Embarrassing.  I'm done programming.  I'm going back to work as a hand model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the only problem, but this line is causing you trouble:

```
ae = models.ForeignKey(ae, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

That's creating a class variable `ae`, so it can't see the module-level class `ae`. That's one reason we usually name classes with mixed case, like `StatementLine`, and name variables in snake case, like `statement_line`. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id37) for the standard guidelines.

However you do it, just make sure that the class name and the field name aren't the same.

Comment: Yes, camel case and snake case works so well when there is more than one word.  Anyway, there's too much magic for me to figure it out and the documents are meant to be read like a novel, not a cookbook.  I'm going to change it to aE